# can't generate key via dnssec-keygen

Tags: bind, dnssec

```
 $ dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n HOST  {host}
```

above results in blank line and endless waiting

```
 $ dnssec-keygen -T DNSKEY -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n HOST  {host}
```

the same

entropy:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail 
890
```

ps. I was trying to make some noise by **find /** but that brought no result

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - have occasion to ask what key do you propose to use to change dns entry  - as i want to make an dynamic changes from my client (host) as i got dynamic ip on home and vps wih dns ( and i want to be sure that this is secure enought - is there a way for me to use my key on pkcs11 device ? )

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  mean that on PKCS11 ii have ECC  private/public keys  and certificates  - i like to reuse them as i do on http server or java apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41284/discussion-between-ceph3us-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `dnsec-keygen` uses `/dev/random` - the generation is slow, so much more in less busy systems.

One of the alternatives is trying to make the system more busy running more processes in the background. It will be still a bit slow, but less slow. Virtual machines are usually less impacted in entropy when using more I/O.

Other alternative is using `/dev/urandom`. `/dev/urandom` is a pseudo-random generator, but unless you are booting the system, should be random enough for your needs.

I advise then to use instead `/dev/urandom` as source, adding to your command `-r /dev/urandom` as in:

```
dnssec-keygen -r /dev/urandom -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n HOST {host}
```

For more, please read:

[Bug 1025554 - generating keys using dnssec-keygen is very slow](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1025554)

As ran by @ceph3us after using the `-r /dev/urandom` parameter,

```
$ dnssec-keygen  -r /dev/urandom -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n HOST  {host}
```

keys generation time:

```
real 0m0.033s 
user 0m0.028s 
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: The `-r /dev/urandom` needs to go at the front of the parameters. I tried the first example and it failed on my install.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Executing `dnssec-keygen` (Version: 9.14.2) with `-r` option will produce the following error: `dnssec-keygen: fatal: The -r option has been deprecated. System random data is always used.`

Comment: @KaiserKatze Good to know that after 3 years they have fixed it on the code. Interesting, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro you're welcome, sir. btw HMAC algorithm is removed from `dnssec-keygen`, come and take a look at my post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523565/how-to-generate-tsig-key-for-certbot-plugin-certbot-dns-rfc2136)